# How to show an element again after removing it from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I am trying to make a script that will hide chat and show it again after pressing the <kbd>H</kbd> button but I don’t know how I need to make the `<div>` elements from the website show again after I remove it. Here’s my code:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Cytos Additions
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @match        https://cytos.io/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var isToggled = false;

function doc_keyUp(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 72: // h
      if (isToggled) {
      
      }
      else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('_1FlWeEtrJKCnvzX-Y50CLP')[0].remove()
      }
      
      var isToggled = true;
      
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', doc_keyUp, false);
```

I don’t know what to put under the `if(isToggled)` statement to make the chat reappear again.

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of removal is insertion; there are various ways to insert an element.
Since your element is at index `0`, [prepending](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend) it to its original parent element is what you need here.

If you just remove an element without retaining its reference, it’s going to be garbage-collected and you cannot use it anymore.
So store a reference to the element; also, store one to its parent, since that’s the target you need to prepend the element to.

```js
const chatElement = document.getElementsByClassName('_1FlWeEtrJKCnvzX-Y50CLP')[0],
  chatParent = chatElement.parentElement;
let isToggled = false;

function doc_keyUp(e) {
  switch (e.code) {
    case KeyH:
      if (isToggled) {
        chatParent.prepend(chatElement);
      }
      else {
        chatElement.remove();
      }

      isToggled = !isToggled;

      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", doc_keyUp, false);
```

Toggling the variable `isToggled` can be done with `isToggled = !isToggled;`, but do not redeclare the variable inside the function, or else it will have no relation to your outer `isToggled` variable.

Note that [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated.
You should use [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) instead.

There are two more concerns:

1. If Cytos depends on the chat existing, then removing the element may cause the app to break.
   Similarly, removing and reinserting elements may cause unforeseen events to be triggered.
   Consider using `case KeyH: chatElement.toggleAttribute("hidden"); break;` instead.
   See the documentation on [`toggleAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute) and on the [`hidden` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden).
2. The class name `_1FlWeEtrJKCnvzX-Y50CLP` doesn’t look like a stable class name, but rather like a minified, randomized name.
   It’s very likely to change and your user script is very likely to break.
   Familiarize yourself with the DOM API, in particular with [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and consider finding a more stable selector.